# Multi figure in one page

Tags: pgfplots

[image]edit same as you but dont help------

```
      \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
    \usepackage{caption}
      \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fullstop}{.\quad}
      \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=fullstop}
    \pgfplotsset{width=120mm}
    \usepackage{subcation}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
          ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 5\\
            4 5\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 8.62\\};
\legend {$Staphylococcus\ aureus$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens $Staphylococcus\ aureus$.}
          \begin{subfigure}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 2\\
            4 3\\
            8 4.8\\
            12 7.8\\
            24 8.162\\};
            24 8.62\\};
\legend {$Escherichia\ coli$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens $Escherichia\ coli$.}
          \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
           color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
           ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 3\\
            4 1\\
            8 2.8\\
            12 2.8\\
            24 2.162\\};
            24 8.62\\};
\legend {$Listeria\ monocytogenes$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens $Listeria\ monocytogenes$.}
          \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
           ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 3\\
            4 1\\
            8 2.8\\
            12 2.8\\
            24 2.162\\};
            24 8.62\\};
\legend {$Listeria\ monocytogenes$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{subfigure}
          \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
          ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 5\\
            4 5\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 8.62\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 2\\
            4 3\\
            8 4.8\\
            12 7.8\\
            24 8.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=halfdiamond*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 3\\
            4 1\\
            8 2.8\\
            12 2.8\\
            24 2.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=triangle*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 4\\
            4 3.3\\
            8 5.8\\
            12 5.7\\
            24 6.162\\};
\legend {$Campylobacter\ jejuni$,C.J1,C.J2,C.J.2}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens $Campylobacter\ jejuni$.}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Also, my friend post here http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=25425

Comment: **why** do keep doing that! **stop deleting questions** only to ask an identical question moments later.

Comment: okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk. Because previously I ask bad way

Comment: You can edit the question. (and just reposting the same question doesn't improve it)

Comment: I thought the person posting there was your friend...

Comment: Why do you have all that code from `\begin{axis}` to `\end{axis}` in your question? It has nothing to do with the problem, and I have asked you repeatedly to please only include code that is relevant. Just edit your question and delete all the lines that aren't needed to show your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use a box.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
    \usepackage{caption}
      \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fullstop}{.\quad}
      \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=fullstop}
    \pgfplotsset{width=120mm}
    \newbox{\mybox}
    \savebox{\mybox}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
          ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 5\\
            4 5\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 8.62\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 2\\
            4 3\\
            8 4.8\\
            12 7.8\\
            24 8.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=halfdiamond*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 3\\
            4 1\\
            8 2.8\\
            12 2.8\\
            24 2.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=triangle*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 4\\
            4 3.3\\
            8 5.8\\
            12 5.7\\
            24 6.162\\};
          \legend {$Staphylococcus\ aureus$, $Escherichia\ coli$,$Listeria\ monocytogenes$,$Campylobacter\ jejuni$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

1. Instead of `\resizebox`, you may adjust the width of plot by passing the `width=0.5\linewidth` option to the axis
2. If you want the individual caption for each plots, use either `subfigure` from `subcaption` package or `subfloat` from `subfig` package.

## Last edit

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
    \usepackage{caption,subcaption}
      \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fullstop}{.\quad}
      \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=fullstop}
    \pgfplotsset{width=120mm}
    \newbox{\mybox}
    \savebox{\mybox}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          color=black,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=0,
          xmax=24,
          %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
          xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
          xlabel=\ {Time},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=10,
          ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
          ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
          y axis line style={black},
          ytick style={black},
          yticklabel style={black},
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line*=left,
          tick align = outside,
          every axis legend/.append style={
            at = {(.5,-.2)},
            anchor = north,
    %       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
            legend cell align = left,
            draw = none,
            legend columns = 2,
          },
        ]
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=square*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}
          ]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 5\\
            4 5\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 8.62\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 2\\
            4 3\\
            8 4.8\\
            12 7.8\\
            24 8.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=halfdiamond*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 3\\
            4 1\\
            8 2.8\\
            12 2.8\\
            24 2.162\\};
          \addplot [
            color=black,
            solid,
            line width=0.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark size=2.5pt,
            mark=triangle*,
            mark options={solid,fill=white}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 4\\
            4 3.3\\
            8 5.8\\
            12 5.7\\
            24 6.162\\};
          \legend {$Staphylococcus\ aureus$, $Escherichia\ coli$,$Listeria\ monocytogenes$,$Campylobacter\ jejuni$}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \caption{my sub figure}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \caption{my sub figure}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \caption{my sub figure}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}
      \caption{my sub figure}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harish I want to individual caption and indivudial 4 figure, also adjust the width. I write all your code , but all times says I have problem.You can see my problem, edit question

Comment: @user67733 Sorry I can't see your problem!

Comment: When I add my code to writer latex says that I have problem

Comment: LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7          \begin{subfigure}

Comment: Dear Harish you see problem?I update my question you can see.

Comment: @user67733 Sorry where did you edit?. I have made my last edit to the answer.

Comment: Above, you can see name -create 4 different figure in one page same of my hand-draw  picture----------edit

Comment: Here new code-which I say you

Comment: @user67733 Will you take some trouble to read my code above? You have to add `\usepackage{subcation}` and change all `\begin{subfigure}` to `\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}`. Please do some reading and pleeease don't post hundreds of lines as code. It is difficult for those to parse your long code.

Comment: Dear Harish,I edit same as you, but dont help all times says that I havee problem, update question-edit same as you but dont help------, you can see

Comment: @user67733 You added `subcation`, I said `subcaption`. Hope you can read. You are putting `\caption{...}` after `\end{subfigure}` Put it before. And you are missing `\begin{document}`. I am out. Sorry for not being able to help beyond this.